# Best practice for mysql server with users logging on from java application

Tags: java, mysql, security

I am working on a java application which will be deployed in the field and needs to connect to an sql database on my company's server.

What is the best practice for users logging in? I have salted and hashed my passwords, and from what I have read I should save the username/salt/hashed password in an sql database. This sounds fine and dandy, but the question becomes how do I get into the database to get the salt without the salt? The obvious answer is to create one account which logs in and only has access to the table of usernames and salts.  This account then "authenticates" the user from that table or kicks them off the server.

Unfortunately, at least in my mind, this introduces a slew of additional security risks. The 'password' for the blanket use account would be available in the source of my java project, as well as any sql script to set up the server. To change that password would also mean a full update to anyone using the project. So, the question I am asking is this:

How can I prevent someone from logging into my sql server from outside of my java application with the credentials I have supplied to that application, or should I not be worried about it?

Here is what I am doing with the server setup file.

```
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ANSI';
CREATE DATABASE PM;
USE PM ;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS PM.drop_user_if_exists ;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE PM.drop_user_if_exists()
BEGIN
  DECLARE foo BIGINT DEFAULT 0 ;
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO foo
    FROM mysql.user
      WHERE User = 'Admin' and  Host = '%';
   IF foo <= 0 THEN
        SET @query1 = CONCAT('CREATE USER "Admin"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "',@PASS,'" ');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @query1; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;       
        CREATE USER 'ParkingManager'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpass';
        GRANT CREATE ON PM.* TO 'Admin'@'%';
        GRANT DROP ON PM.* TO 'Admin'@'%';
        GRANT LOCK TABLE ON PM.* TO 'Admin'@'%';
        GRANT ALTER ON PM.* TO 'Admin'@'%';
        GRANT SELECT ON PM.* TO 'Admin'@'%';
        GRANT UPDATE ON PM.* TO 'Admin'@'%';
        GRANT SELECT ON PM.* TO 'ParkingManager'@'%';
        GRANT UPDATE ON PM.* TO 'ParkingManager'@'%';
        CREATE DATABASE PMUsers;
  END IF;
END ;$$
DELIMITER ;
CALL PM.drop_user_if_exists() ;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS databaseName.drop_user_if_exists ;
SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE ;
```

Thanks!

Edit: The company does not want a VPN. They say that it shouldn't be necessary because the server has SSL.

Comment: Your sql server should not be accessible from outside. That's the only way you can make it secure and prevent others to access it from the outside. Then install a VPN so that you can have access to your database (if you dont' have a fisical access to the server). Only your webserver should be accessible to the outside. The comunication between the webserver and the sql server uses your intranet

Comment: So I need a web server to securely access my sql database? I guess this would need to be php (not something I know how to do)?

Comment: What I mean by web server is something like apache.

Comment: Well the company DOES have a server... so I should be making them log on to that server and then have it connect to the sql database as admin@myserver?

Comment: Ok, so you have one server with apache and mysql installed. And you want to prevent other not autorized persons to be able to access the mysql server right?

Comment: Right. I want to be able to connect from anywhere with my java application and if possible only have access to certain tables within the database.

Comment: But your java application will be running in the same server, or in your computer?

Comment: The java application will be running on several different computers.